# "0 second ago" should be "0 seconds ago" in the chatroom info page

Tags: bug, chat, plurals

When you post a message in a chatroom and then refresh the info page immediately afterwards, you'll get this, which says `0 second ago`. It should say `0 seconds ago` instead.

[image]